# Как убрать выбросы повторно?

Tags: python

Есть датасет:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ux75KAlqTUPfixwKBcZb8YkSA_vfjWLp/view?usp=sharing
Нужно разбить его на недели и даже после этого получить нормальное распределение,
которое лучше получить присвоив среднее значение ближайшей недели.
После первого удаления выбросов перед разбивкой на недели получаем рис. верхний,
после разбивки на недели получаем рисунок нижний, то есть выбросы все равно есть.
Как от них избавиться после разбивки на недели?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, как вы удаляли выбросы до разбивки на недели, но что вам мешает применить тот-же метод к датафрейму, полученному после разбивки?

Но это чисто технологический вопрос. А есть еще и концептуальный - какие данные вы собрались считать выбросом после разбивки? Глядя на ваш рисуночек видно, что классических выбросов там практически нет, впрочем, как и на исходном графике.  "Не все то выбросы, что торчит"- имейте это ввиду. Не знаю, что вы там за задачу решаете, но выбраковав не глядя "как бы выбросы" вы получите риск построить модель, очень далекую от адекватной.

Ну и вот эта ваша фраза вводит читающего в ступор:
 *и даже* (что значит "даже"?) *после этого получить нормальное распределение* (получить нармальное распределение просто отбраковкой каких-то данных невозможно), *которое лучше получить присвоив среднее значение ближайшей* (одной???) *недели* (еще раз, это не метод получения нормального распределения, особенно, если исходное распределение не нормальное или (похоже - как у вас) имеет тренд.

Кстати, на всякий случай, вы уверены, что вас интересует именно нормальность распределения, а не его стационарность?

Comment: Да, на самом деле затупила, только что увидела, что мне здесь уже дали функцию clip, она все нормализует как надо повторно.